# Multpile inheritance and different kind of method. What does these kind of method and inheritance mean?

Tags: oop, c#-4.0, methods, multiple-inheritance, xero-api

Hi I need a bit of help understanding these codes. These are from Xero Api and unfortunately there is no commenting so am struggling to understand the below codes.

```
    public abstract class XeroReadEndpoint<T, TResult, TResponse> : IXeroReadEndpoint<T, TResult, TResponse> 
                where T : XeroReadEndpoint<T, TResult, TResponse>
                where TResponse : IXeroResponse<TResult>, new()

    public interface IXeroUpdateEndpoint<T, TResult, TRequest, TResponse>
                : IXeroCreateEndpoint<T, TResult, TRequest, TResponse>
                where T : XeroReadEndpoint<T, TResult, TResponse>
                where TResponse : IXeroResponse<TResult>, new()
                where TRequest : IXeroRequest<TResult>, new()

public IEnumerable<TResult> Delete<TResult, TResponse>(string endPoint) where TResponse : IXeroResponse<TResult>, new();

public IEnumerable<TResult> Put<TResult, TResponse>(string endPoint, object data) where TResponse : IXeroResponse<TResult>, new();

public IEnumerable<TResult> Get<TResult, TResponse>(string endPoint) where TResponse : IXeroResponse<TResult>, new();
```

I do understand the concept of inheritance and object-oriented programming. But I am a confused in the codes in the interface and the abstract class.

Also am struggling to understand the below three methods too. I get the return type but what does <> just after the method name means. And what does it mean by new() in all the cases.

Can someone please tell the actual meaning of above codes. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To start, there is no multiple inheritance in C#.  What you're seeing is multiple interface implementation, which means the code will expose the same interface contracts, but not share any implementation.

Types contained within the angle brackets are referred to as generic type arguments.  The easiest way to explain is with the IList and IList interfaces.  IList is an interface where implementations store objects using list semantics (that is, its an ordered set of objects).  The problem is that anything you store in it is cast to an object, and so you can store in an IList instance a System.String in the first position, and a System.Int32 in the second.  If you just want a list of Strings, no help from the compiler or IList.  Generics solve this; an IList may only contain types of String, and the compiler will enforce this, and you can be sure you'll only get string instances from instances of an IList.

The final part of your question is the new; generic type arguments can be limited.  The `where` porition of those declarations puts limits on what the generic type argument can be; for the Get method, you can use any TResult (TResult is a place holder for a type name) provided the type implements IXeroResponse.  The new() means that the type you use for TResponse must also have a public default (parameterless) constructor.

You can read more about generics at MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx

More on constraining generic type arguments: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx

Answer (score 1):

For example  where TResponse : IXeroResponse , new() means the  TResponse must be of type IXeroResponse and new() means TResponse must have parameterless  public constructor.

In general the format is **where T: Myclass, new()** means T must be of type MyClass and MyClass must have one parameterless public constructor